# How to loop through mismatched data

Tags: python, excel, csv, date, text

So I have been trying to think of how this would be possible, but nothing comes to mind.

I have 2 csv files with dates and data in them. The dates, however, are mismatched. I want to be able to write a code that allows me to loop through all the data, find the matching dates, and then create a text document with the date in common and the 2 data values from the separate sheets. The other alternative is matching them myself in excel.

Any suggestions?

Ex. of what I am trying to accomplish:

Say I have this file1:

```
01/01/01 | 1 
01/02/01 | 2 
01/03/01 | 3 
01/04/01 | 4 
01/05/01 | 5 
01/06/01 | 6 
01/07/01 | 7 
01/08/01 | 8
```

and this file2:

```
01/05/01 | 9  
01/06/01 | 22 
01/07/01 | 33 
01/08/01 | 44
01/09/01 | 55
01/10/01 | 66
01/11/01 | 77
01/12/01 | 88
```

What I would hope to have returned is (after running a loop):

```
01/05/01 | 5 | 9
01/06/01 | 6 | 22
01/07/01 | 7 | 33
01/08/01 | 8 | 44
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of lists to store the data from the CSV files, then find those items in the dict that have more than one value in the list.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

merged = defaultdict(list)

for filename in 'f1.csv', 'f2.csv':
    with open(filename) as f:
        for date, value in csv.reader(f, delimiter='|'):
            merged[date].append(value)

with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')
    for date in sorted(merged):
        if len(merged[date]) > 1:
            w.writerow([date] + merged[date])
```

This will (almost) produce the file that you require, the only difference being that the delimiter is a single `|` instead of `|` (with surrounding spaces). I also assumed that the input files are similarly delimited.

Answer (score 1):

I think pandas join logic is well suited for this task since you are effectively asking for an inner join as keyed by date.

First define a parsing function for your dates (which I added in case you needed to treat these as actual dates for further processing in python). Then load each csv file into a separate dataframe. Finally join and drop `NaN` values to get the inner join you seek (or just explicitly inner join by setting `how` parameter in `join` function). You can also easily drop the outptut dataframe into a csv file with the `to_csv` function.

If you are looking to get a little more creative with aggregating or joining then pandas is the way to go.

```
import pandas
parser = lambda date: pandas.datetime.strptime(date.strip(), '%y/%m/%d')
dt = pandas.read_csv('H:\\one.csv', parse_dates = [0], date_parser = parser, index_col=0, delimiter="|", names = ["date", "val"])
dt2 = pandas.read_csv('H:\\two.csv', parse_dates = [0], date_parser = parser, index_col=0, delimiter="|", names = ["date", "val2"])
dt.join(dt2).dropna().to_csv("H:\\output.csv")
```

This would also work but you lose all of the date-specific functionality within python:

```
import pandas
dt = pandas.read_csv('H:\\one.csv', index_col=0, delimiter="|", names = ["date", "val"])
dt2 = pandas.read_csv('H:\\two.csv', index_col=0, delimiter="|", names = ["date", "val2"])
dt.join(dt2, how='inner').to_csv("H:\\output.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

- Read the first record from each file, **r1** and **r2**
- Extract dates **d1** and **d2**
- while there's remaining data in both files:

  - if d1 == d2:

    - merge records and print
    - get next line of each file (new **r1** and **r2**)
  - else if d1 < d2

    - get next **r1**
  - else

    - get next **r2**

Briefly, you're stepping through both files, keeping a "bookmark" in each.  If the records match, merge them and print; advance both files.  Otherwise, advance the bookmark that's "behind" in the date.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSV module to read out both files, convert them to a dictionary which maps `date` => `list[values]`, then prints them.

```
import csv

# Extract CSV
csv1 = []
with open('first.csv', 'r') as f1:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f1)
    for row in csv_reader:
        csv1.append(row)

csv2 = []
with open('second.csv', 'r') as f2:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f2)
    for row in csv_reader:
        csv2.append(row)

# Initialize dict which will map dates to values
d = {}

# Map dates to values by getting a default array and appending the values
for row in csv1:
    v = d.get(row[0], [])
    v.append(row[1])
    d[row[0]] = v

for row in csv2:
    v = d.get(row[0], [])
    v.append(row[1])
    d[row[0]] = v

# Print results
for k, v in d.items():
    values = ' | '.join(list(map(str, v)))
    print(f'{k} | {values}')
```